# White Screen Issue in react native android

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to the react native. When I launched the application after installed in my mobile white screen appeared for 2 to 3 seconds, then only my application loaded. this issue appeared when launch the app more than 2 times and it appears only in android not iOS. Can anyone please help me to sort out this issue.

Androidmanifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" />
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
  <meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
 android:value="AIzaSyDerv_tN-WH7gsjksngkjD3jSw0DCZnypf1M6lC82jI"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_oak_leef_white" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Have you added some sort of code or are you just trying to run the pre-generated app?

Comment: I am just close and re run the app

Comment: Can you share your AndroidManifest.xml and your navigator file?

Comment: I have added in the description.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by expo's OTA updates feature. The app is checking for updates on load by default and that takes time.

Add `"updates": {"checkAutomatically": "ON_ERROR_RECOVERY" }` to your `app.json` to fix this.

You will have to rebuild and reinstall your app for this to take effect.

Comment: I have added "updates": {"checkAutomatically": "ON_ERROR_RECOVERY" } in my app.json. but still issue appeared.